# Login Security Philosophy

Tags: authentication, security

I have been given some code of some other developer, who has created some login security policies. For example, if you try to login with a username that exists in the database, it will begin recording the amount of failed login attempts. Then after it reaches 3 login attempts, it adds another entry in the logs but adds the bit 1 to LockedOut.

Do you guys believe this is a good security policy? Wouldn't someone trying to gain entry just try a large number of random usernames and forcibly lock everyone out of their account? It seems kind of a bad philosophy for security.

I would think a better security procedure would be to lock out anyone who has made 3 attempts according to an IP table that tracks various user attempts and expires within 30 minutes or so to prevent DDoS.

How do you guys design your login security ?? Here's what this developer did basically:

```
if username is in database:
   if first login: increase fail-attempt counter.
   if second login: lock out username.
   else: don't let him in.
else:
incorrect password.
```

edit: Final procedure:

```
public void ResolveTimeouts()
{
    if (data.Expire <= DateTime.Now)
    { // it will only delete ONE single entry from the database, 
      // that happens to be this user's IP
      // If and only if, The expiration date is older than right now.
        Delete(this.data);
        data.Attempts = 0;
    }
}


int uid = UserExists(username);
if(uid < 1){
  ResolveTimeOuts(); // this will delete IPs from table if expiration passed
  if(loginAttempts >= 3){
    "Fail login, you have been locked out for " + TIMEOUT + " minutes";
    ExtendExpiration(TIMEOUT);
  } else {
    IncrementAttempts();
    "fail login, incorrect username or password.";
  }
} else {
  if(authenticate(uid, password)){
    "Successfully logged in.";
  } else {
    // INSERT lock out specific username feature here.
    "failed login, incorrect username or password.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree. I feel like locking the username altogether is safer (without regard to IP).

What happens when the malicious hacker fakes an IP address? The hacker can shuffle through IP addresses and continuously brute-force the username.

I lock out after three attempts for 15 minutes.

Comments on your edit:

I would do something like this:

```
if(resolveTimeOuts()){ 
  bool uid = UserExists(); 
  //do other stuff
}else{ 
  "Your IP has been locked. Enter this code to prove you are human."
  // Captcha or math equation.
}
```

Though, I wouldn't delete expired IP requests in `resolveTimeOuts()`. It could increase the execution time of the function. Do something like this:

```
if(resolveTimeOut()){ 
  bool uid = UserExists(); 
  //do other stuff
}else{ 
  "Your IP has been locked. Enter this code to prove you are human."
  if(rand(1,5) == 5){
     // or something equivalent
     deleteExpiredRequests();
  }
  // Captcha or math equation.
}
```

This would give the fasted execution of `resolveTimeOut()` and if the IP is requesting too fast, all of the expired timeouts would be deleted then. Kind of a double-whammy for the DoS hacker. They get a different page and the generation of the page could be slowed through `deleteExpiredRequests()` if there is a large amount of expireds.

Edit two:
This is more or less something I would implement. I would write the full code, but I program in PHP.

```
bool function humanRequest(){
    // decide if the request lag is humanistic or bot speed
    // for example: last_request > this_request - 500;
}

if(!humanRequest()){
    // redirect to a Captcha page or die with a warning or something (like SO does)
}
uid = getUsername(username);
if(uid > 0){
    // validated request
}
else{
    // increase attempts
    // you could have a separate column for IP requests or whatever
    // lock out username after 3 attempts
}
```

You **could** put the `humanRequest()` in a both cases of the username validation. Basically, if they are requesting any username within a short period of time, black list them. But if you are validating usernames in a special page (that only is included when someone is attempting to login), this will already take care of it.

This way, you only need to add another table. No need to modify the table you have.

Comment: @Jason, but then they can lock out a number of users for hours and it doesn't actually prevent brute forcing.

Comment: @Dexter - it prevents brute-forcing, but not Denial of Service (as you pointed out).

Comment: I don't know much about preventing it, but I would probably start by recording IP address and check the current visit time with the last visit time. There has to be a difference between a human accessing and a bot accessing (time between requests could be ms instead of seconds).

Comment: Of course, like I said, I've never done any research in it or ever looked into ways of preventing it. That is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: I see. Let me clarify what ResolveTimeout does though, maybe it's not that many queries or slowness. Updating original post.

Comment: That works fine, but I don't see anything that prevents DoS? Seems you just delete the IP entries. I assume there is much more to the overall code.

Comment: If attempts are zero. Then IncrementAttempts(); will add 5 minutes to expiration and insert the IP into the database. This prevents DDoS because it would require the person to constantly change IP.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm guessing this also means that we don't have to do "username-account-specific-lockouts" which would prevent an account lockout attack.

Comment: I'm not sure you have prevented DoS attack, though. What happens if the IP brute-forces usernames? I would have a separate database structure altogether that holds the IP and last_access_time. Before you query the username, check that IP request didn't happen too soon after the last request.

Comment: Yes if the attacker brute forces a specific username, then it will lock out those specific usernames. Indeed it makes it so that they can indeed do an account-lockout-attack. Do you suggest completely forgetting about specific username locking and just focus on the IP-lock? (remove the UID conditional).

Comment: Lock out username (without regard to IP), after three attempts. Have a separate table that stores usernames and if they are accessing too fast, make them do something that only humans can do. I'll re-edit my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: I see what you did. With human request testing, you'd still have to look into IPs, so maybe it's not that much different than locking out the person after 3 tries for 5 minutes or showing CAPTCHA. I'm proficient in PHP btw. I want to avoid CAPTCHA for now but yes that is the better solution than lock out. My code is very similar to yours except for the humanrequest difference.

Comment: You don't have to use Captcha, that's just an example. You could lock the IP for a few minutes. Or you could generate an access forbidden header (I don't know the ramifications of that though). Captcha's just an example that many people use. When I lock a username out, I don't give the option of Captcha. They are just locked out for 15 minutes. However, if I __were__ to lock out IPs I would do a Captcha.

Comment: Is it a bad thing if I lock out people based on IP?

Answer (score 2):

The best-of-both-worlds approach I've seen is to use a Captcha on the form after N failed login attempts.

This allows the real user, who may have honestly forgotten their password the option to continue trying, albeit more slowly, and effectively stops automated brute force attacks. This makes it irrelevant how many IPs the attacker is using.

Comment: This would be ideal. However, I don't want to rely on an external service for this particular application. Do you recommend custom coding a simple riddle or math captcha would be a good idea?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on Captcha.  The original was cracked easily, and the replacements will be cracked as well.  There are other, better options for turing tests.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560/most-effective-form-of-captcha

Comment: I'm not sure that "what I think of the code" will be a good answer.  I have issues with the formatting and variable naming to start with, and my mind refuses to read the code without wanting to re-do it myself.  First, using an int when it should be a bool for the uid variable (which should be named more clearly, something like "UserExists" rather than uid)...  And so on.  I think it's bad code, but I think it's logically sound. I'd also not hard code the number of minutes, but include it in the web.config so it can be changed more easily, etc.

Comment: *shorter answer*   I think the code is logically sound, but hard to read, and personally, I'd think about moving the items that may change (like the desired lockout time) to the web.config instead of hard-coding.

Comment: @David, I used int for uid, because I am going to use it in authenticate(uid, password), so I don't have to requery user table again. It's definitely pseudocode, not real code, simplified for everyone to quickly grasp the concept. Yes, I agree web.config seems a good idea (how did u know i was using asp.net?).

Comment: This is the only practicable solution. If you start locking users, an attacker will just brute force user names and lock everyone out. The thinking of throttling or locking is just sooooo 1998 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to limit the number of login failures over a period of time, then either disabled the user for a while or refuse to accept further logins from that IP address for a while.

The point of the exercise is to prevent brute force attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than get into my own personal philosophy, I'd defer to people who think about proper security and nothing else.

That said, there are certain guidelines and standards that are accepted as best practices. I'd suggest starting at OWASP: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication

The normal pattern is to disable the user after a certain number of attempts for a time period to prevent brute force.  The usual standard that I've seen in practice in well-written web apps is 3 invalid attempts results in a lock-out of 1 hour.

By the way, the specific quesiton of lock-out is covered on the OWASP website here: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Implement_Account_Lockout

Quote from the article (bolding added by me for emphasis):

> If an attacker is able to guess
>   passwords without the account becoming
>   disabled due to failed authentication
>   attempts, this provides the
>   opportunity of the attacked to
>   continue with a brute force attack
>   until the account is compromised.
>
> Automating brute-force/password
>   guessing attacks on web applications
>   is a trivial challenge. Password
>   lockout mechanisms should be employed
>   that lock out an account if more than
>   a preset number of unsuccessful login
>   attempts are made.
>
> Password lockout mechanisms do have a
>   logical weakness, however. It is
>   possible for an attacker to attempt a
>   large number of authentication
>   attempts on known account names
>   resulting in locking out entire blocks
>   of application users accounts.
>
> Given that the intent of a password
>   lockout system is to protect from
>   brute-force attacks, **a sensible
>   strategy is to lockout accounts for a
>   number of hours. This significantly
>   slows down attackers, while allowing
>   the accounts to be open for legitimate
>   users**.

Comment: Seems like a plan but, I don't like the wording they've used. Locking out account names would be a problem, as the text says, but then it contradicts itself by saying 'lockout accounts for a number of hours,' that would block entire groups of users from accessing the system.

Answer (score 1):

A compromise would be to lock for a short period of time so to considerably slow down automated attacks, but not too long for the legitimate user who made a "legitimate" error. IMHO, 10 seconds could be enough in most cases, **if strong password policy is enforced**.

Comment: That might be enough. That is why I am planning on making an IP table, with Attempts and Expire columns. Although I'm worried about them simply brute forcing a number of SQL queries, but hey, one query is not so bad.

Comment: If you plan to store IP addresses/nb of attempts, you could also implement a logic which would detect massive login failures from a given IP and ban that IP for a longer period of time. Even if attacker has many IP addresses (e.g. using a botnet), it would take ages before the password gets cracked (if, again, it's a strong password with min. 8 chars length, forbidding dictionary words and having all classes of chars)

Comment: yes I plan on using the Attempts to lock out the user after 3 tries for 10 minutes. And during each login attempt, I first resolve any timeouts/expirations (so that they are only deleted as the user tries once more).

Comment: Any lockout, even a short one, can seriously inconvenience the real user. No company wants to explain to a user that they can't access their account because it's under attack. The method needs to stop automated attacks while still being transparent to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you serve corporate customers, you can't lock users out by IP.  Corporate firewalls usually tend to hide the users' IP addresses from the web server.  Three unsuccessful attempts by any three users behind the firewall could lock out an entire organization (or one really stupid user who never checks to see if his caps lock if pressed).

Comment: A corporate firewall cannot hide a user's IP, that's how servers communicate through the IP. You can't have communication without internet.

Comment: A firewall can hide a user's ip address when employing Network Address Translation.  The firewall defines a client port for the outgoing connection to the server that maps to the user's internal IP address.  Most corporations don't have users with publicly addressable IP's.  That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: Ah you're saying, that some companies prefer to keep everyone in their network at the same exact IP and just port forward everything, well what exactly happens when the same ports are constantly used after hundreds of people. IPs are there for a reason, a company has to be pretty stupid to do that, and yes you should lock them all out if they choose to do something this silly.

Comment: Not some companies, most companies.  Firewalls are designed to handle this.  Each request gets a port to use for the length of the request (the request and the response then the request is over).  That's what Network Address Translation is all about.  But the IP address is usually singular.  Sit behind a corporate firewall and visit whatismyip.com and you'll find that all users have the same public IP address.