# Codeigniter: Replace captcha in Tank_auth

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

Has anyone ever tried to replace the default captcha in Tank_Auth with their own customized captcha? The default captcha for Tank_Auth is just too difficult for most users. I want to replace it with [Cool Captcha](http://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha) and would like to know if replacing it is a good or bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this. I replaced Codeigniter's default catpcha with Cool Captcha. Download a copy of it in my [github Tank_Auth fork](https://github.com/enchance/Tank-Auth).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this atm. You might want to do some research on captcha first though. A lot of these are even easier to get past if they are easy to read.

Check out this related question:
[Most effective form of CAPTCHA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560/most-effective-form-of-captcha)

And these two blog posts dealing with that same question:
http://www.evengrounds.com/developers/alternatives-to-captcha
and
http://www.sitepoint.com/captcha-alternatives/

Of course it all depends what and where you use your captcha.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure tank_auth to use reCaptcha, you have to edit the config file

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned 2 simple steps.

1. Go to 'yourprojectname/application/config/tank_auth.php'.
2. Search for `$config['captcha_registration'] = TRUE;` make it `FALSE`