# How to convert text to captcha image using javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, captcha

I am designing a web page for registration and I need captcha image for security each time.

How can I convert text to captcha images ?

Comment: Captchas are there to stop spambots, which don't usually run javascript - so if you make your captcha js-dependant, it will not stop any bots

Answer (score 2):

You should not have the answer to the captcha challenge on the client side (HTML page on the browser). That's where it can be read from by anything non-human that's trying to beat the challenge. And if you're looking to generate the image in the browser using javascript, you'd need to have the answer on the client side to begin with.

Take a look at server side captcha options, either offered as a service like [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) or some library or script for your chosen programming language.

Be aware that even correctly implemented captchas can be beaten relatively easily either automatically by text recognition (OCR) or [manually](http://www.blackhat-seo.com/2009/captcha-farms/).

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560/most-effective-form-of-captcha) for prior discussion. For alternatives to the traditional text recognition captcha, see [In Search Of The Perfect Captcha](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/).