# PHP unaccepted text form

Tags: php, html

recently I started getting bots from one website that keeps posting their website links in my "Customer Feedback" form. I want to make my form deny any text that contains "http://" or any other words/phrases I will add (they will surely find a way to bypass the "http://"), but the thing is I don't know how to do so. Here is the code (the forms that need to be checked for "http://" are $name and $comment):

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i');
    $checkIp = mysql_query("SELECT ip from comments WHERE ip = '$ip'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($checkIp) > 0) {
        echo "Only 1 feedback per IP allowed!";
        $IP = mysql_fetch_array($checkIp);
        print_r($IP);
    }
    if($name){
        if($email){
            if($comment){
                if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment, ip, datetime) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment','$ip','$datetime')");
                }
                else                        
                    echo "The email address is invalid!<br><br>";
            }
            else
                echo "You haven't entered any comment!<br><br>";
        }
        else
            echo "You haven't entered an email address!<br><br>";
    }
    else
        echo "You haven't entered your name!<br><br>";  
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use a [captcha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560/most-effective-form-of-captcha)?

Comment: do you have an ip for their server?

Comment: You should learn about security, your code is dangerous for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check and see if a substring is contained in the `$name` or `$comment` variables like so:

```
if (strpos($comment,'http://') === false and strpos($name, 'http://') === false) {
    echo 'continue executing your code here';
}else{
    echo 'Its a bot!';
}
```

Comment: For some reason it only works if in the comment box I only enter "http://" but if I enter "http://d" for example, it lets it go through...

Comment: If you enter d;? Why wouldn't you want that to go through?

Comment: I mean "http://" and then any letter/number it goes through, but if I enter only "d" without the http:// it does not go through and gets it as a link...

Comment: I am so sorry! I gave you the code backwards. I have updated my answer; it should work now!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it didn't look right, from my knowledge of LUA, but I thought that LUA has nothing to do with this..

Comment: Yah, sorry about that. If it works for you, would you mind accepting and +1? Thanks.